# Pre-compiling googletest to run on baremetal

Tags: cmake, googletest, bare-metal

I've been trying to use google test on bare metal and followed the slightly harder variant of the website below to precompile google test, obtain the library file and then link it in a project's CMake

https://clarkli86.wordpress.com/2016/01/28/build-googletest-for-baremetal-targets-stm32/

The CMake runs smoothly throughout the project, in which I'm trying to integrate google test, up to the part it starts building google test

The CMakeLists file of the folder containing the tests and google test looks like this:

```cmake
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_tst)
set(SOURCE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

#add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest/)

add_executable(${BINARY} ${SOURCE})

add_test(NAME ${BINARY} COMMAND ${BINARY})

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest/googletest/include/gtest)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest/googletest/include/gtest)

target_link_libraries(${BINARY} PUBLIC Library gtest)
```

which gives the following error:

```terminal
SDK_test/testing/main.cpp:3:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [testing/CMakeFiles/SdkTest_tst.dir/build.make:63: testing/CMakeFiles/SdkTest_tst.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:9691: testing/CMakeFiles/SdkTest_tst.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

On the main.cpp file, gtest is called using:

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
```

I've tried to build the project using this flag:

```terminal
-l/testing/googletest/googletest/include/gtest
```

include the path directly in the CMakeLists, and all result in the error above

If I uncomment the add_subdirectory line, the make build fails due to the pthreads and sleep libraries
examples:

```terminal
testing/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1453:24: error: 'nanosleep' was not declared in this scope
   nanosleep(&time, NULL);
testing/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1499:3: error: 'pthread_mutex_t' does not name a type
  pthread_mutex_t mutex_;
```

Any suggestions on how to properly link the library?

Comment: It seems you did not disable the use of `pthreads`, which will be unavailable on a baremetal target: the article you are pointing to  is very clear and  does use the  `--without-pthreads` option for doing so. You need to do the same  with your cmake-based solution.